# Do electrical arcs in vacuums have voltage drops?

Tags: electricity, voltage, vacuum

I have looked for a long time online but have found no answer to this question.

I have however found two things: Vacuums are neither conductors nor resistors, it takes a fairly large voltage for arc to form in vacuums. Also, if you can get an arc to flow, current is limited only by external limitations.

So is there a voltage drop across a vacuum arc? Does it lose any energy? If so how much compared to a spark in air?

Comment: it is similar to this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/xtube.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the arc to exist, there must be an electric field and therefore, voltage. The energy of the field in vacuum is spent on speeding up charge carriers.

Common examples of electric current in vacuum are vacuum tubes and CRT's, where voltage is distributed or drops along the path of electrons from cathode to anode.